# Adding new pages in Jupyterhub

Tags: jupyterhub

I have deployed JupyterHub and I am currently customizing the JupyterHub interface and was wondering how I could add pages to the JupyterHub website. I have tried using "Command: sudo nano test.html" to create another page but unfortunately, the page shows <404 error>. I have tried using "Command: locate test.html" however, could not locate the page even though I have saved it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to add pages to JupyterHub installation with just HTML. However you can see how to extend JupyterHub with python at [the pages handler file](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/blob/master/jupyterhub/handlers/pages.py).